# Replication Publication Configuration

Tags: sql-server-2005, merge-replication

When trying to configure a publication I get the below error.

```
SQL Server could not configure 'MyServer' as a Distributor.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

The server 'MyServer' is already defined as a Distributor. To reconfigure the server as a Distributor, you must first uninstall the exisiting Distributor. Use the stored procedure sp_dropdistributor, or use the Disable Publishing and Distribution Wizard.
Changed database context to 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 14099)
```

How can I tell if this is configured to be a distbitor...Becuase when I go back a few steps in the wizard tot the "Distbutor" step I tried use the option that says

> "Use the following server sas the Distributor (Note: the server you select must arelady be configured as a a distbutor. )"

but when I select this option and try to add the MyServer I get the erorr:

> 'MyServer' is not configured as a Distributor. Select a server that is configured as a Distributor.

The server is not currently a distrutor (that I know of)  and the wizard seems to think it is and it isn't. Am I crazy???

**EDIT:** 
Mirroing is setup on the database and server that I am trying to configure. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to use sp_dropdistributor, but I was able to add a distributor of my choosing after that.